# pymssql error in pip additional requirements for apache airflow 2.5

Tags: python, airflow, pymssql

Adding `pymssql` to `_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS` while setting up apache airflow 2.5 container has been giving error. The worker container keeps running again and again because it is not able to install pymssql. My laptop is running macOS with M1 chip.

```
Collecting pymssql==2.2.5
Downloading pymssql-2.2.5.tar.gz (170 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 170.1/170.1 kB 1.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [6 lines of output]
setup.py: platform.system() => Linux
setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', '')
setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.17')
setup.py: include_dirs => []
setup.py: library_dirs => []
setup.py: could not locate 'clock_gettime' function required by FreeTDS.
[end of output]

Note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

Note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0.1
[notice] To update, run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, kindly tell more on the installation setup, where it is installed ? using Docker or something else ?